# TypeError when sum value of dictionnary for each key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to sum one value that contains list inside value dictionary.

I want to sum value of key `'x1'` in `dataX` dictionary that contains list (`[12, 14, 10, 16, 18, 24, 12]`) but it goes wrong and an error appears.

Here is my dictionary:

```py
dataX = {'x1' : [12, 14, 10, 16, 18, 24, 12], 'x2' : [10, 11, 14, 13, 15, 20, 8]}
```

the output should :

```
106
```

Here is my code:

```py
sum = 0
for i in dataX:
    sum += dataX[i]
```

But, I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/s6/_5szgcrd2cl86md1wj_kw_th0000gp/T/ipykernel_18467/658532054.py in <module>
      9 sum = 0
     10 for i in dataX:
---> 11     sum += dataX[i]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use the built-in sum() function

You need to use the sum built-in function, **but be careful**, you are doing **name shadowing** with the variable `sum`.

In programming, shadowing refers to the act of reusing the same name for a variable or function (here, `sum`) in an inner scope (your file), hiding its definition in an outer scope (built-ins). This can result in the outer definition being temporarily inaccessible (you can't use `sum` in your file), because the inner definition takes precedence (your `sum` variable, an int).

> ⚠️ If you are using **Jupyter Notebook** or an **interactive
> session**, please note that you need to restart the python session
> even if you changed the variable in the code, because `sum` has
> changed in the memory frame of the session. You need to restart Python
> to restore the `sum` function.

If you want the sum of each values:

```py
sum_dict = {}
for key in dataX:
    sum_dict[key] = sum(dataX[key])

print(sum_dict)
# {'x1': 106, 'x2': 91}
```

## Some improvements

### iterate over key-value pairs

`dict.items()` allows you to iterate over the dictionnary with pairs of key and value together, which make manipulation of data less boilerplate.

```py
sum_dict = {}
for key, values in dataX.items():
    sum_dict[key] = sum(values)

print(sum_dict)
# {'x1': 106, 'x2': 91}
```

### Use dict comprehension

If you want a dict with keys and total for each list, a dict comprehension is fine since this operation is simple and can be expressed like this without reducing readability.

```py
sum_dict = {key: sum(values) for key, values in dataX.items()}

print(sum_dict)
# {'x1': 106, 'x2': 91}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more issue in your code;

You are using the builtin `sum` as your variable name.

It will override the builtin function and will not add values. `sum` will behave as an integer.

***It is strongly advised not to use builtin function names like `list`, `sum`, etc. as your variable names.***

you can get the sum of value by:

```
dataX = {'x1' : [12, 14, 10, 16, 18, 24, 12], 'x2' : [10, 11, 14, 13, 15, 20, 8]}
sum(dataX['x1'])
#106
```

or

```
for i in dataX:
    print(sum(dataX[i]))
106
91
```